# Preserving Alphabetical Order Within a Citation

Tags: citation, mla

I am using MLA format to cite a series of articles for a school paper. All citations are listed alphabetically (Flood --> Gould --> Green -->).

However, I am wondering whether or not an article with multiple authors would list the authors in alphabetical order as well or if the listing is arbitrary. I believe I have generally seen multiple authors alphabetized, but I cannot find any evidence of this in my usual go-to place (the [Purdue OWL](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_general_format.html)). For example, in a paper by Wolf-Peter Schill and Claudia Kemfert, NoodleTools (my citation generator of choice) alphabetizes the authors by last name:

> Kemfert, Claudia, and Wolf-Peter Schill. *The Solution*...

Conversely, NoodleTools exports an article by Paul D. Thacker and Jon Tennant as:

> Thacker, Paul D., and Jon Tennant. "Why We..."

Is alphabetization correct? Did NoodleTools make an error? Does Thacker's middle initial somehow upset this rule? Any clarification is much appreciated!

Comment: Generally, the authors should be listed in the same order as they are in the work being cited.  In some cases the order will be "pecking order", in others alphabetical or some other criterion.

Comment: This question might get better answers (or have been asked before) on academia stackexchange.